# How to solve for $y$ on five equations

Tags: polynomials

It has been over ten years since I've taken an algebra course so I'm sure I am doing something simple incorrectly. I have a series of five equations. Given a specific $x$ value (body weight) I want to determine the $y$ value (score on a fitness test). I know 11 values and want to use the equation to determine the intermediate values.

The following are the formulas as determined by Excel:

[image: Formulas as determined by Excel]

And here are the values that I have:

```
BW   UNT     NOV     INT     ADV     ELT
114  2.000   3.465   4.105   5.667   7.333 
123  2.000   3.472   4.146   5.650   7.325 
132  2.008   3.492   4.136   5.644   6.424 
148  2.000   3.486   4.176   5.628   7.169 
165  1.952   3.394   4.073   5.491   6.964 
181  1.923   3.337   3.989   5.354   6.878 
198  1.848   3.217   3.859   5.136   6.591 
220  1.750   3.050   3.668   4.868   6.241 
242  1.661   2.893   3.442   4.554   5.831 
275  1.502   2.611   3.113   4.102   5.240 
319  1.323   2.298   2.740   3.605   4.596
```

I want to be able to plug in intermediate values (121, 155, etc) and get the appropriate value. So if I solve for $x = 114$ I would except to get $y = 2.000$ for the first formula, $y = 3.465$ for the second, etc. However [when I put the first formula (UNT) into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%20%3D%20-0.0102%28114%29%5E2%20%2B%200.0584%28114%29%20%2B%201.9332) for $x = 114$ I get $y = -123.968$

Comment: are you sure you are not solving $f(x-x_s)$ rather than $f(x)$ i.e. the polynomial for the first one is $$-0.034(x-x_s)^2 + 0.1712(x-x_s) + 6.954$$, where $x_s$ is some characteristic shift..i.e if we use $x_s = 114.0$ then we yield 6.954 which corresponds more closely to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are not solving $f(x-x_s)$ rather than $f(x)$ i.e. the polynomial for the first one is $$-0.0102(x-x_s)^2 + 0.0584(x-x_s) + 1.9332$$, where $x_s$ is some characteristic shift..i.e if we use $x_s = 114.0$ then we yield 1.9332 which corresponds more closely to the solution. or better still $\bar{x} = \frac{x}{x_s}$ which leads to 
$$
-0.0102\bar{x}^2 + 0.0584\bar{x}+ 1.9332
$$
where if we have $\bar{x} = \frac{x}{114}$ we find the first equation to be
$$
f(114) = -0.0102\left(\frac{114}{114}\right)^2 + 0.0584\left(\frac{114}{114}\right)+1.9332 \approx 1.95276
$$
-0.0102(114)^2 + 0.0584(114) + 1.9332

Comment: So if I were solving for $x_s = 155$ would it be $\left(\frac{155}{114}\right)$?

Comment: Click the WA link. He means the bottom one by first.

Comment: Yes sorry I was referring to the bottom one by first (which is confusing). But it does look like this formula is what I actually need to use.

Comment: @PhillipCopley almost, but for the point $x = 115$ you place $\bar{x} = \frac{155}{114}$ into the polynomial (as written above) the $x_s$ is a normalizing unit, which i use 114.

Comment: @Arthur cheers I will modify.

Answer (score 1):

There are no mistakes in Wolfram Alpha's calculation or your input.

Excel is acting weirdly though. It seems it somehow doesn't recognize the x-values. This can already be seen by the fact that the x-axis on the graph is not to scale. I think it calculates the formula based on the points $x = 0,1,2,\ldots, 10$. Look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+-0.0102%28x%29%5E2+%2B+0.0584%28x%29+%2B+1.9332+for+x%3D0+to+x%3D10, this looks like an approximation to your graph.

Comment: That does make sense, depending on what formula I use in WF I am consistently getting results in the $-120$ to $-500$ range.